# Rescue from Multiple Errors

Tags: ruby, error-handling, capybara, rescue

I have a few error conditions that I want to log and move then move on to the next test in a loop.

The error handling & `rescue` found below is part of a method `by_the_test` and the `next` statement is in there; after this has done its job.

On its own, the single `rescue` below works, creates an entry in the error log and moves on to the next test. Lovely.

```
rescue RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError
  $logfile.puts "#{Date.today}:  Error for Row #{$row} - Expected #{@ct_cd}, but got #{@court.text}"

  puts "Error for Row #{$row} - Expected #{@ct_cd}, but got #{@court.text}"
```

When, I added the following extra `rescue` statements and the tests hit one of them, `rescue` didn't work.

```
rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound
  $logfile.puts "#{Date.today}:  Error for Row #{$row} - Entry #{@endor_cd} not found"

rescue Capybara::Ambiguous
  $logfile.puts "#{Date.today}:  Error for Row #{$row} - Duplicated entry on record #{@endor_cd}"
```

I also tried the following:

```
rescue RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError, Capybara::ElementNotFound, Capybara::Ambiguous
```

and I received a generic error message in the logfile.

Comment: Show the error you get

Comment: The error I'm getting is: Unable to find css "li.category" with text "ZZ20" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Comment: Worked it out - the rescue statements needed to be in a different place. Cheers @EVAL for the editing.

Comment: @Peter please answer your own question to close it and assist others in the future.  I'm always happy to see experts answering their own questions.

Answer (score 0):

The first rescue statement was in the correct place, the second & third needed to be moved earlier in the code as the error they rescue from occurs in a different place.

Lesson learned - check the error statements!